# HOw To Keep Sounds To BUttons

Tags: iphone

HI Guys, 
This is jagadeesh, iam beginner of This i Phone Application development Platform 
please do help me to b a good iphone Developer 
let me know some useful  Blogs  & forums for iPhone application Development
  i need small clarification Regarding 2 things

1--->> How to Keep a sounds to Buttons( i mean if i want to press a buttons in the Calculator application we have many Buttons , whenever i press the required Button it will give particular sound)
2--->>.How to reduce the size of the Icon ( I mean if my icon size is 57 x 58 & i want to convert it  into 48 x 49 size Icon) please give me suggestions to do this 
- Show quoted text -

Answer (score 1):

1. Add the following method to one of your button's actions:

   -(IBAction) buttonPress:(id)sender {

   ```
   if (!self.tickSound)
       self.tickSound = [[SoundEffect alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: @"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf"];
   }
   [self.tickSound play];
   ```

   }
2. Do you need to change the icon size from within your app, or on the Mac to include it in your app?  BTW, iPhone app icons have to be 57x57, if that is what you are using this icon for.