# keeping Sounds to Button

Tags: iphone

Hi any one please Let me knw how to Keep Sounds to a Button called "  Press Me "

Comment: Mmm? How to play sound on button click? Or smth else? You should explain your problem clear to get good fast answer.

Comment: This looks very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503139/how-to-keep-sounds-to-buttons

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

1) Add the following to your view controller's .h file:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
...
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController {
 ...
}
...    
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;
```

2) Create a button in Interface Builder

3) Right click on the button in Interface Builder, select the second tab, and drag from the circle next to "Touch Up Inside" to the "File's Owner" in the .xib window, and select the "buttonPressed" method

4) Add the following code to your view controller's .m file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mysound" ofType:@"wav"];
  SystemSoundID mySound;
  AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &mySound);
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound); 
}
```

5) Finally make sure you link to the Audio Toolbox framework... you can do this by going to Add to Project... from the Project Menu, navigating to /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulatorXX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks and choosing AudioToolbox.framework.  Make sure you select not to copy, and "Relative to Current SDK" from the menu that pops up.

Hope this helps!